# your connection to this site is not secure

Tags: localhost

I have tried several times in my localhost I can't able reload the site in my google chrome browser so can someone give me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This means that this Website Doesn't have SSl Certificate and that your friend data is exposed during his journey on this website

Comment: This does not gives an answer you can comment it instead of answering. look here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer